# RegExp starting with uppercase and finish by lowercase or is a number

Tags: regex

Looking for a regexp which match with characters starting by an uppercase and finish by lowercase or a number
For example :

`Foo2B => Foo, 2, B`

I find `^([A-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]*)` but it return `Foo, 2B`

Comment: Do you mean like this? `[A-Z][a-z]*|\d+` https://regex101.com/r/V9ksrw/1

Comment: The current problem is misunderstanding of what `^` does. Do not use it like this if you do not want to only match at the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The `|` character means "OR", so your regex is actually matching two different things - either `[A-Z][a-z]*` OR `[0-9]*` at the beginning of a string.

What you're looking for is this: `^[A-Z][a-z0-9]*`. This matches a leading uppercase letter, followed by a lowercase letter or number repeated zero or more times.

Answer (score -1):

The regexp was OK
I didn't used it well in JavaScript that's why I though the regexp was wrong.

For information

```
'Foo2B'.split(/([A-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]*)/).filter((elem) => elem !== '')
```

Comment: Never use `.split()` if you mean `.match()`. When extracting text, use `match` or `matchAll`. Use `'Foo2B'.match(/[A-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]+/g)`